# Recursion stack in Binary search tree

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I am trying to delete a node from a binary search tree. While this function works properly why do we need to set node->m_left or node->m_right to return value of deletenode function itself? It is hard to understand this recursive structure.
currently doing it only for the leaf node

```
Node<T>*  deletenode(T key){
         return deletenode(key,this->root);
        }
        Node<T>*  deletenode(T key,Node<T>* node){
            Node<T>* temp;
         if(node==nullptr){
             return node;
         }
         if(key<node->m_data){
             node->m_left=deletenode(key,node->m_left);
         }
         if(key>node->m_data){
             node->m_right=deletenode(key,node->m_right);
         }
          
         

         return temp;
        }
```

Comment: you don't have to return the node if it's value doesn't change within the function. otherwise you need to return, since the function operates on its own copy of the passed pointer and the caller will be unaware of the changes unless getting reassigned to the returned value

Comment: *Need* to? It is possible to write a recursive function that doesn't. What are you actually asking?

Comment: @Beta why are we setting this "node->m_left=deletenode(key,node->m_left);"

Comment: So that if `m_left` points to the node to be removed, the call to `deletenode` will return `nullptr` and we will set `m_left` to that.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the left or right to the *result* of calling the deletenode function on that branch, not to the function itself.

The recursion means: "If my tree has a left branch and a right branch, and the item to delete is in the left branch, then make a new tree that has the same right branch, but the result of removing the item to delete from the left branch as its left branch"

Comment: A big tree is made of two small trees, left and right.  If you delete an item from the left tree, and you delete it from the right tree, then it is no longer in the big tree. You have deleted it from the big tree.

If the left and right trees are also big trees, the way to delete from them is exactly the same